# Create an admin menu in a MENU_LOCAL_TASK

Tags: routes

I have added a MENU_LOCAL_TASK to a node. Within that local task I want to display an admin menu block using `system_admin_menu_block_page()` however I always get `You do not have any administrative items.` I have no trouble getting admin menu pages to work as MENU_NORMAL_ITEMS. Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Code below.

```
function my_module_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['node/%node/settings'] = array(
    'title' => 'Account settings',
    'description' => 'Manage your account settings.',
    'page callback' => 'system_admin_menu_block_page',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access arguments' => array(1),
    'access callback' => 'my_module_access_account_settings',
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'file path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'system'),
    'file' => 'system.admin.inc',
    'weight' => 1000,
  );
  $items['node/%node/settings/upgrade'] = array(
    'title' => 'Upgrade your account',
    'description' => 'Use this form to upgrade your account.',
    'page callback' => 'my_module_upgrade_account',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access arguments' => array(1),
    'access callback' => 'my_module_access_account_settings',
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );
  $items['node/%node/settings/cancel'] = array(
    'title' => 'Cancel your account',
    'description' => 'Click here to cancel your account and remove all your data.',
    'page callback' => 'my_module_cancel_account',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access arguments' => array(1),
    'access callback' => 'my_module_access_account_settings',
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );
  return $items;
}

function my_module_access_account_settings($node) {
  if ($node->type == 'my_node_type') {
    return TRUE;
  }
  return FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further investigation reading the code [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/system_admin_menu_block/7), it appears that this can be done.

For example, `admin/tasks` has admin menu children in a `MENU_LOCAL_TASK` however, it appears that it looks at the current local task's parent item and then looks for `MENU_NORMAL_ITEM` children.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work in my case since I use wildcard urls (%node) and my local task is not the default one. (like the `admin/tasks` one is).

So I came up with a workaround function that achieves what I need.

The function `my_module_account_settings($node)` basically queries the DB for the current `MENU_LOCAL_TASK`'s `mlid`, then queries the database for ALL menu links that have the current `MENU_LOCAL_TASK`'s `mlid` as their parent.

I then call the theme function for `admin_block_content` and boom.

Let me know if anyone comes up with either a better, or more correct way of doing this.

```
function my_module_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['node/%node/settings'] = array(
    'title' => 'Account settings',
    'description' => 'Manage your account settings.',
    'page callback' => 'my_module_account_settings',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access arguments' => array(1),
    'access callback' => 'my_module_access_account_settings',
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'weight' => 1000,
  );
  $items['node/%node/settings/upgrade'] = array(
    'title' => 'Upgrade your account',
    'description' => 'Use this form to upgrade your account.',
    'page callback' => 'my_module_upgrade_account',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access arguments' => array(1),
    'access callback' => 'my_module_access_account_settings',
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );
  $items['node/%node/settings/cancel'] = array(
    'title' => 'Cancel your account',
    'description' => 'Click here to cancel your account and remove all your data.',
    'page callback' => 'my_module_cancel_account',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access arguments' => array(1),
    'access callback' => 'my_module_access_account_settings',
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );
  return $items;
}

function my_module_account_settings($node) {
  $current =  menu_get_item();

  // get current MENU_LOCAL_TASK mlid
  $current_mlid = db_select('menu_links' , 'ml')
    ->condition('ml.link_path' , $current['path'])
    ->fields('ml' , array('mlid'))
    ->execute()->fetchField();

  // get all menu_links where the parent link id is the current 
  // MENU_LOCAL_TASK
  $rows = db_select('menu_links' , 'ml')
    ->condition('ml.plid' , $current_mlid)
    ->fields('ml' , array('mlid', 'link_path'))
    ->execute()->fetchAllKeyed();

  foreach ($rows as $mlid => $path) {
    // load each of the admin menu items within this local task
    // in my case i replace the placeholder/wildcard with the node nid
    $item = menu_get_item(str_replace('%', $node->nid, $path));
    if ($item['access']) {
      $items[] = $item;
    }
  }

  // return the themed block
  return theme('admin_block_content', array('content' => $items));
}

function my_module_access_account_settings($node) {
  if ($node->type == 'organisation') {
    if (user_access('edit org account settings')) {
      return TRUE;
    }
  }
  return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: The problem in `system_admin_menu_block_page()` is that for your menu item, `if ($item['tab_root'] != $item['path']) { $item = menu_get_item($item['tab_root_href']); }` is selecting the parent menu item of node/%/settings (node/%); as consequence of this, the value for mlid is not the value assigned to node/%/settings (your menu item). I tried setting `$item['tab_root']`, and `$item['mlid']` in `hook_menu()`, but I was still getting the "You do not have any administrative items." message. Your code is probably the only solution.